# Data graph labels cut off on c3.js chart

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, c3.js, linegraph

I'm graphing some lines on a c3.js line chart, but the data label of the leftmost point is being cut off:

[image]

I've tried adding padding to the chart, but this just adds padding to the overall chart.  What I need is some way to add some sort of padding to just the bar graph ticks.

Something that I've considered:

I've considered using the "transform" property:

```
.c3-texts .c3-text text {
  transform: translate(10px, 0);
}
```

But moving the position of all the data labels to the right would end up causing the data labels on the right-hand side of the graph to get  cut off.

Here's a simple example of labels getting cut off:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x4dzmg0y/)

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]
        ],

        labels: {
         format: function(x){
             return "Test Label"
         }
        }
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code for your chart?

Comment: @ksav Sure, I'll update the post with an example.

Comment: Have a look here: http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-x-padding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ksav pointed me in the right direction. I remember trying this before, but foolishly, I didn't think of putting decimal numbers. I had tried putting in the value 1, and it gave way too much padding, but doing the following worked perfectly:

```
axis: {
  x: {
    padding: {
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
    }
  }
}
```